# how to share my whole tree (host: Windows 7) with my virtual machine (guest: Kubuntu 11.10)?

Tags: windows, mount, vmware, share

I am running VMWare workstation.

I would like to share my whole tree with my Guest OS. Currently I am sharing a directory using the line below

```
.host:/ /home/username/Documents vmhgfs auto,rw,exec,utf8 0 0
```

I already tried using C:/ but something I am missing in order to mount it properly. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should have a read through the documentation on the [VMware support page](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_running9.html) for this but to summarise;

> To share files between a host computer and a virtual machine or
> between two virtual machines, you use the networking features of
> VMware Workstation. If you know how to share files between two
> physical computers on a network, you already know how to share files
> with a virtual machine.
>
> This section describes four scenarios for sharing files between two
> systems, either a host computer and a virtual machine or two virtual
> machines, where
>
> - Both systems run Windows operating systems, using Windows file    sharing
> - You are connecting from a Linux system to a Windows system, using smbmount
> - You are connecting from a Windows system to a Linux system, using    Samba
> - Both systems run Linux operating systems, using NFS, FTP and Telnet
>
> You can apply the same principles to share files between virtual
> machines. Configuration for FreeBSD guests is similar to that for
> Linux guests.